# How do I programatically change layers in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I don't want to the show the layers control on the map, but I want to put some buttons somewhere else to change between layers. Is this possible to change the layer programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have a `map`:

```
var map = L.map('worldmap-map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
```

To remove a layer, `layer1`:

```
map.removeLayer(layer1)
```

To remove a control layer, `ctrlLayer`,

```
map.removeControl(ctrlLayer)
```

Or you want to add a `layer1` to `map`:

```
layer1.addTo(map)
```

For an example, there is a `Leaflet` example : http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth-example.html

You could use firebug or chrome dev tools to see its source.

Comment: This doesn't answer the "change layer" part of the question.

Comment: @Jeff If I remember it right (I used leaflet a long time ago), `removeLayer` doesn't destroy a layer.  So you could add use buttons to add or remove layers accordingly, which in a sense implements the "change layer" function.

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/33762133/4355695 : Just `myTileLayer.addTo(map)` does the job of changing background layer (without adding on top), if it is already part of the base layers. And you don't need to explicitly remove the previously selected background layer.